# Editing headers of a .dex file before apk signing

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dex

I am particularly new to the Android Security Realm and trying to understand how Android, during installation(and execution) of an apk file, validates its integrity.
Just to try my hands on, I tried recompiling an apk with three .dex files and changing one byte of of the contents in the header section of only one of the classes.dex using a Hex Editor before signing it.
The App installed on the device with almost no complaints but with much shorter time as it usually does.
On trying to run the App, as expected, it crashed complaining it can't find the Application class and the required .dex file isn't present in the /system/... path.

I want to understand why the App installed successfully in the first place and Android didn't complain of corruption during installation. Also, What are the checks which Android is actually placing during the installation which detects this corruption.

P.S.: I changed one byte in the SHA-1 header of one of the .dex file(classes.dex particularly)

Answer (score 1):

As you found, an invalid dex file won't cause installation to fail. Typically, as part of the installation process, art will optimize and compile the dex file - the result of which is an oat file. It's during this process that the dex file is checked for integrity.

You can take a look at art's source to see what kinds of verification it performs on the dex file. See e.g. [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/verifier/method_verifier.cc), but elsewhere as well.